# Eliminate blocking javascript not using async or defer

Tags: javascript, html

My site uses floatbox for showing gallery's and single images. Running the site through Lighthouse, the later keeps 'complaining' that floabox.js is a render blocking resource. Next to the JS-file I also have to load floatbox.css, which comes with the script, the get it working.

I tried using defer as well as async, however both seems to mix up things resulting in a non-working functionality. So, basically the out of the box set up is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://some_site/floatbox/floatbox.css"> 
<script src="https://some_site/floatbox/floatbox/floatbox.js" type="text/js"></script>
```

One of the other Lighthouse recommendations was to have the css file being non-blocking. I managed to solve this suggestion by the following script:

```
<script>
    var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = '//some_site/floatbox/floatbox.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
    };
    var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
    if (raf) raf(cb);
    else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

My question is how I can load the floatbox-script in a way that is not render-blocking? I do prefer a non-jQuery solution.

Thanks for your time!